# R2020b: App Designer says can't open File MATLAB failing if condition

Tags: matlab

How to solve this

[image]

C:\Users\SHUBHAM\Documents\MATLAB\Dymola_App.mlapp: Can't open file.

What I did is:

I created a GUI in MATLAB using AppDesigner

When  I click Run it says that "C:\Users\SHUBHAM\Documents\MATLAB\Dymola_App.mlapp: Can't open file."

After close look I see that it is due to if condition

[image] This is failing

[image] This is working

Comment: You can try adding nested if

Comment: Thank you it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested if condition worked but dont know why that failed!